# Etherscan says "we were unable to locate a matching bytecode (err_code_2)"

Tags: etherscan, error

[image]

Please help me with this error...

I dont know what is it?

Comment: You might have enabled optimization while deploying your contracts. Try setting it true in the etherscan.

Comment: same error and of course I checked the optimization